# How to display the date when user types date?

Tags: javascript, date, chatbot, gupshup

I'm unable to fetch and display the date from "**http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Etc/GMT+7**"
but i'm able to display the date and time using the inbuilt function but i want to display it using the api.

```js
function MessageHandler(context, event) {
  if (event.message == "date2") {
    context.simplehttp.makeGet('http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Etc/GMT+7', null, parser);
  }
}

function parser(context, event) {
  var dateJson = JSON.parse(event.getresp);
  var date = dateJson.date;
  context.sendResponse("Today's date is : " + date);
}

function MessageHandler(context, event) {
  if (event.message == "date") {
    context.sendResponse("Today's date is :" + Date());
  }
}

function EventHandler(context, event) {
  context.simpledb.roomleveldata = {};
  MessageHandler(context, event);
}
```

I'm using gupshup IDE, whenever I give the input date2 I'm getting these lines in bot log

> 2407: [2019-03-08T09:00:33.249] [INFO] default-Setting Up Bot Event For Bot=> /devnode/Displayinhthedate
>   2408:[2019-03-08T09:00:33.250] [INFO] default - Setting Up Bot Context For Bot =>/devnode/Displayinhthedate
>   2409:[2019-03-08T09:00:33.252] [INFO] default-Successfully connected to: /devnode/Displayinhthedate/temp_db
>   2410:[2019-03-08T09:00:33.285] [INFO] default-Successfully Fetched Data For Key=>bot:global
>   2411:[2019-03-08T09:00:33.291] [INFO] default-Successfully Fetched Data For Key =>room:1234

Comment: Any errors?  Console error, server errors?

Comment: I'm using gupshup IDE, whenever I give the input date2 I'm getting this lines in bot log 
`2407: [2019-03-08T09:00:33.249] [INFO] default-Setting Up Bot Event For Bot=> /devnode/Displayinhthedate 2408:[2019-03-08T09:00:33.250] [INFO] default - Setting Up Bot Context For Bot =>/devnode/Displayinhthedate 2409:[2019-03-08T09:00:33.252] [INFO] default-Successfully connected to: /devnode/Displayinhthedate/temp_db 2410:[2019-03-08T09:00:33.285] [INFO] default-Successfully Fetched Data For Key=>bot:global 2411:[2019-03-08T09:00:33.291] [INFO] default-Successfully Fetched Data For Key =>room:1234`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
var dateJson = JSON.parse(event.getresp);
var date = dateJson.date;
```

you are getting the date as `dateJson.date` but there is no key with `date` in the JSON object.

```js
{
  "week_number": "10",
  "utc_offset": "-07:00",
  "unixtime": "1552031359",
  "timezone": "Etc/GMT+7",
  "dst_until": null,
  "dst_from": null,
  "dst": false,
  "day_of_year": 67,
  "day_of_week": 5,
  "datetime": "2019-03-08T00:49:19.371885-07:00",
  "abbreviation": "-07"
}
```

The date you can get by using `dateJson.datetime`.
Hope it will help.

Comment: function parser(context, event) {
           var dateJson = JSON.parse(event.getresp);
           var date = dateJson.datetime;
           context.sendResponse("Today's date is : "+date);
       }

I've made the suggested changes yet its not working

Comment: JSON.parse will give you the dateTime property as a string. Do you need then to explicitly convert it to a Date object?

Comment: No just need to be able to fetch any of the property and display datetime is an example
`function MessageHandler(context, event) {
         if(event.message== "date2") {
               context.simplehttp.makeGet('http://date.jsontest.com/',null,parser);
           }
       }
       function parser(context, event) {
           var dateJson = JSON.parse(event.getresp);
           var abbreviation = dateJson.abbreviation;
           context.sendResponse("Today's date is : "+abbreviation);
       }`
this is the code i'm trying to run now but same problem exists.

Comment: you have two functions with the same name: `MessageHandler`, please try to write single function with two conditional blocks on `event.message`. and run and also please share the error you are facing. and also try to `console.log(event.getresp)` and `consol.log(dateJson)` to see what is inside.